# Cannot use method with argument in mapper file

Tags: datamapper, mybatis

Java 1.7, WildFly 8, MyBatis 3.2.6, PostgreSQL 9.4.

I have prototype that is simple system to lend books. I use MyBatis as ORM. All was fine and dandy until I tried filters.
There is table of books. Getting list of books is defined in mapper like this:

```
<select id="selectBooks" resultType="org.bookman.json.library.JsonBook">
  select id, created, inclusion_date as inclusionDate, title, author
  from bok_books
  <where>
    <if test="filter('title') != null">
      title ilike #{filter('title')}||'%'
    </if>
  </where>
  order by ${orderCols}
</select>
```

There are two methods used in EL - filter(String) and getOrderCols(). Select is called in this way:

```
TableReqHnd bookHnd = new TableReqHnd();
... // among other things sets filter data
List<JsonBook> books = sqlSession.selectList("selectBooks", bookHnd, rowBounds);
```

This is how TableReqHnd class looks:

```
public class TableReqHnd
{
  private Map<String, String> filters        = new HashMap<>();
  ...
  public String getOrderCols()
  {
    ...
  }
  ...
  public String filter(String fieldId)
  {
    if (!filters.containsKey(fieldId)) return null;
    return filters.get(fieldId);
  }
}
```

Why I did it like that? It allows me to reuse TableReqHnd object for any table, just with defined new values for ordering, filters etc. I don't have to create separate class for each table with its own setters and getters for each filter.

Now problem itself. Method getOrderCols() works fine, but filter(String) does not. Here is what exception is thrown: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=9jAjBhtd

It throws essentially java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: filter(java.lang.String). I find it strange. This method certainly exists in TableReqHnd: public String filter(String fieldId). ${orderCols} works fine (it is just simple getter public String getOrderCols()).

According to OGNL specs, call

```
filter('title')
```

should be correct. Exception in fact confirms it should be possible, it just cannot find method for some reason. Anyone knows if it can be fixed somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try

```
<select id="selectBooks" paramType="org.bookman.json.library.JsonBook">
  select id, created, inclusion_date as inclusionDate, title, author
  from bok_books
  <where>
    <if test="filter('title') != null">
      title ilike #{filter('title')}||'%'
    </if>
  </where>
  order by ${orderCols}
</select>
```

Comment: Tried that, more specifically <select id="selectBooks" parameterType="org.core.db.TableReqHnd" resultType="org.bookman.json.library.JsonBook">. Didn't work. Still thanks for try. :)